# Why does SymPy 1.1.1 return an error when computing this basic integral?

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math, calculus

I am trying to integrate `x**(n-1)*sin(x**n)` using SymPy 1.1.1. Any idea why the error

> TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational

is generated? Is this a known issue? Is this a bug? Or am I doing something wrong?

```
pip list | grep sympy
sympy                              1.1.1
```

running on

```
cat /etc/*release
Manjaro Linux
DISTRIB_ID=ManjaroLinux
DISTRIB_RELEASE=17.1.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=Hakoila
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Manjaro Linux"
Manjaro Linux
```

Using Anaconda latest Python

```
$python
Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Apr 29 2018, 16:14:56) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux
>>> from sympy import *
>>> x, n=symbols('x n')
>>> integrate(x**(n-1)*sin(x**n),x)
```

gives

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/integrals/integrals.py", line 1295, in integrate
    risch=risch, manual=manual)
  File "/opt/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/integrals/integrals.py", line 486, in doit
    conds=conds)
  File "/opt/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/integrals/integrals.py", line 908, in _eval_integral
    h = meijerint_indefinite(g, x)
  File "/opt/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/integrals/meijerint.py", line 1612, in meijerint_indefinite
    res = _meijerint_indefinite_1(f.subs(x, x + a), x)
  File "/opt/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/integrals/meijerint.py", line 1675, in _meijerint_indefinite_1
    if b < 0 or f.subs(x, 0).has(nan, zoo):
  File "/opt/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/core/relational.py", line 195, in __nonzero__
    raise TypeError("cannot determine truth value of Relational")
TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational
```

Computing the antiderivative using Mathematica,

```
ClearAll[x,n]
Integrate[x^(n-1) Sin[x^n],x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: You may need to some how put constraints on `n`.  If `n=0`, the `x**(-1)` term will introduce a `ln(x)` term, that isn't there with positive `n` integers.  And float `n` adds a further complication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SymPy tries several methods, roughly in this order: Risch algorithm, Meijer G integration, "manual integration" (based on calculus-type rules) and a slow heuristic form of Risch. Meijer G throws an error here, which it a bug (`if b < 0` should be rewritten with the consideration that the truth value of `b < 0` may be unknown).

As a workaround, disabling Meijer G helps:

```
x, n = symbols('x n')
integrate(x**(n-1)*sin(x**n), x, meijerg=False)
```

returns `Piecewise((log(x)*sin(1), Eq(n, 0)), (-cos(x**n)/n, True))` which is more correct than Mathematica output, recognizing that the case n=0 is different.

In the current development version of SymPy, this output is reordered to put the generic case first: `Piecewise((-cos(x**n)/n, Ne(n, 0)), (log(x)*sin(1), True))`.

One can also use the option `manual=True` to tell SymPy to go straight to "manual" algorithm, with the same outcome.

```
integrate(x**(n-1)*sin(x**n), x, manual=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Declaring the types of `x` and `n`:

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> x = Symbol('x',real=True)
>>> n = Symbol('n',integer=True)
>>> integrate(x**(n-1) * sin(x**n),x)
-cos(x**n)/n
```

It took several **minutes** for `integrate` to return the antiderivative. However, using the declaration `x, n = symbols('x n')` instead, it also worked. I am using **SymPy 1.0** and **Python 2.7.12**.

Comment: I need to add a `positive=True` to `n` to get this result.

Comment: @hpaulj What error message do you get if you only use `n = Symbol('n',integer=True)`?

Comment: The truth value one that OP reported, issued by `def __nonzero__(self):`.  I suspect 1.1 has been making changes in assumptions (loosening them).  But I'm still trying to find the relevant documentation.